# Query to retrieve a list of recursively defined parents

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to fetch a list of IDs containing the IDs of all the parents of a given record.

Table: carrier_products(id, carrier_product_id)

I have so far come up with this

```
carrier_products.id IN
                 (WITH RECURSIVE tree(id, carrier_product_id) AS (
                  SELECT cp.id, cp.carrier_product_id FROM carrier_products cp WHERE cp.id = ?
                    UNION
                      SELECT cp.id, cp.carrier_product_id
                      FROM carrier_products cp JOIN tree ON cp.carrier_product_id = tree.id
                    )
                  SELECT id FROM tree)
```

but this doesnt work correctly, any advice?

Comment: Can you set up a sqlfiddle and edit your question with the desired results?

Comment: Do you want all the parents or all the ancestors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful of what exactly you want to retrieve. Here you want a table with all the ancestors, so the table you create with `WITH RECURSIVE` should only have one field (`id`). Also, be careful with the end condition of your recursion (test of `null` value). Here is a solution :

```
postgres@localhost testdb=# create table carrier_products(id integer unique not null, carrier_product_id integer);
CREATE TABLE
Temps : 33,361 ms

postgres@localhost testdb=# insert into carrier_products(id, carrier_product_id) values (0, null);
INSERT 0 1
Temps : 3,005 ms
postgres@localhost testdb=# insert into carrier_products(id, carrier_product_id) values (1, 0);
INSERT 0 1
Temps : 1,151 ms
postgres@localhost testdb=# insert into carrier_products(id, carrier_product_id) values (2, 0);
INSERT 0 1
Temps : 0,978 ms
postgres@localhost testdb=# insert into carrier_products(id, carrier_product_id) values (3, 1);
INSERT 0 1
Temps : 0,676 ms
postgres@localhost testdb=# select * from carrier_products;
 id | carrier_product_id
----+--------------------
  0 |               NULL
  1 |                  0
  2 |                  0
  3 |                  1
(4 lignes)

postgres@localhost testdb=# WITH RECURSIVE tree(id) AS (
  SELECT cp.carrier_product_id FROM carrier_products cp WHERE cp.id = 3
  UNION
  SELECT cp.carrier_product_id
  FROM carrier_products cp JOIN tree ON cp.id = tree.id and cp.carrier_product_id is not null
)
SELECT id FROM tree;

 id
----
  1
  0
```

Comment: Worked perfect, much appreciated, but why but i specify the and cp.carrier_product_id is not null

Comment: It's to avoid to have the `null` in your result set.